# Most related Hypernym of a synset in some context

Tags: wordnet, hypernym

I have a word say w. For w, I used [Lesk algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesk_algorithm) to get the synset s it should belong to given I have a context. Now for this synset s, I want a hypernym out of all the hypernyms such that it is also most relevant in the context of the word w. Is there an algorithm for this in python?